# Redirect banners URL

Tags: url, redirect, banner

I am wondering, is there is an option to change the urls behind the banners in your networks or to change the banners with your own banners? I mean, in your own LAN to change all banners on every webpage (not owned by you) with your own banners?

Thank you!

Comment: banners? What banners?

Comment: I mean advertisements

Comment: Are you running a proxy?

Comment: I thought about using a proxy server. Maybe something like MITM proxy and modify the HTML with it. However, in this case I have to require all the clients to set proxy in their browsers. Instead, I was thinking for something as bridge between the router and the Internet. Something like FreeBSD. Then on the bridge to modify the responses from the application server that client would like to access

Comment: You mean like... a proxy?

Comment: Maybe SQUID and transparent proxy?